# How to make multi-step form in Rails and prompt user to sign-up after filling form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model in my rails App called "Request". It consist around of the 12 fields. It has relations with user model like User has_many: request, Request belongs_to: User. For users i use Devise. My problem is next. I want that user from home page of my app has a possibility to start creating new request. It should be multi-step form like 3 steps with 4 inputs in each step. After filling all step i need to prompt user to sign up. I don't want that new row in Request table would be created until user would do Sign up. So the process should looks like user goes throw each step, we store all input data by someway, after user do sign-up we create new user in Users table and new request in Requests table. I don't want to store request until user would be registered because in this case i would have in my db a lot of requests that don't belong to any user. So how could i achieve my aim?
UPDATE:
So with users suggests and with searching i get some progress. So now i have form on one page (all 12 fields), after click on submit it goes to "create" action in RequestController where i do such code:

```
if current_user.nil?
  session[:request] = params
 # Redirect the user to register/login
  redirect_to new_user_registration_path
```

So i get all params, store them in session[:request] and redirect to Sign-up page. Than in ApplicationController i have added code:

```
if session[:request].present?

        # save list
        @request = current_user.requests.create(session[:request]["request"])

        # clear session
        session[:request] = nil
```

which connect request parameters with current_user and create new record in db.
So now only one problem, how to make multistep for my form, which in final result would be sent to create action?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the [wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) for step by step wizard.

And in the first step html template keep only the input fields which you require , and in second step store the first step values in hidden field, similarly in third step you can store first and second step values in hidden field.

and in controller Just assign the values in @request variable

```
steps :step_one, :step_two, :step_three

def request_steps
 @request = Request.new
 @request.assign_attributes(params[:request])
 case step
 when :step_one
   #add code here you want to do in step one
 when :step_two
   #add code here you want to do in step two
 when :step_three
   #add code here you want to do in step three
 end
 render_wizard
end
```

Alternate solution:
If you don't want to store in hidden field  and not using wicked and have multiple steps actions then another solution is to store the request inputs in session like below:

```
def step1
  session[:user_request] ||= {}
  session[:user_request].merge!{params[request]} #merge input from step1
  # render to show step2 
end

def step2
  session[:user_request] ||= {}
  session[:user_request].merge!{params[request]} #merge input from step2
  # render to show step3 
end

def step3
  session[:user_request] ||= {}
  session[:user_request].merge!{params[request]} #merge input from step3
  # render to login/signup_page 
end
```

and after user login you can find the request data using session[:user_request] and save the request with logged in user and clear session[:user_request] like in your devise session controller

```
after_filter :after_login, :only => :create

def after_login
  if session[:user_request]
    request = current_user.requests.build(session[:user_request])
    session[:user_request] = nil if request.save
  end
end
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about wicked gem, but this gem doesn't solve few of my problems. First: as i wrote, i don't need to save data in database on any step. We should show user all steps, make inputs validation etc. then after last step filling prompt him sign up/log in and after success signup and login we should save request data to db.

Comment: Ok. You can still save the user inputs in hidden fields 
and use the assign_attributes method which will keep user inputs from different steps in request instance variable like this
`@request.assign_attributes(params[:request])`
and store values in hidden fields in next step till we come to the last step that is signup so it would also go in params in form submit.
and at the signup/login request you can use these request values like `@user.requests.build(params[request])`

Comment: This method @request.assign_attributes(params[:request]) - where i should use it, i mean in which controller/action? Also, how could i prevent saving data to db until sign-up?

Comment: If you are not using wicked and you have different actions for different steps then you may write this in all actions of steps and lastly override the devise to save request after login/signup.

Comment: How could i direct my from to step action instead create action in the controller? Please also check my post, i have added update, i think with your advice i'm very close to right solution

Comment: You are directly assigning the params to session[:request] instead you can assign blank hash if not present and then use merge! method to merge the input from other steps like below:

`session[:request] ||= {}`
and then
`session[:request].merge!{params[request]} #merge input from step`

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be to store the values on Front-end, and in the last step send all the informations. This can be achieved using javascrit, and all the variables would be naturally stored in variables. I think this is one of the the easiest ways.

Another idea is to create a few methods in controller (and routes) that gathers all the informations, it can be like (using preferable ajax, or normal post requests):

```
def step1
    params = params[:params]
    #...
end

def step2
    params = params[:params]
    #...
end
```

And then you can create a column that temporarily [stores](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) all the informations (in just on column, in format json or hash), and it just send to the right columns after the user confirmed all the infos.  You can then create a cron job to delete records from temporaries columns.

These are just a few suggestions. I'm looking foward to see more ideas.